# R fread and strip white

Tags: r, csv, fread, strip, removing-whitespace

I have a csv file with extra white spaces that I want to read into R as a dataframe, stripping the white spaces.

This can be achieved by using

```
testdata<-read.csv("file.csv", strip.white=TRUE)
```

The problem is that the dataset large and takes about half an hour.
The fread function is at least twice as fast but does not have the strip.white function.

```
library("data.table")
testdata<-data.frame(fread("file.csv"))
```

Is there a quick way to strip the white spaces from the columns after reading in, or is there some way to strip the white spaces using fread?

If it was just a one time import, I wouldn't mind that much, but I need to do this several times and regularly.

Comment: There is a parameter `strip.white` which is set by default to `TRUE` in fread right now and you can also pass `data.table = FALSE` to fread to receive a `data.frame` after reading the dataset

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a parameter `strip.white` which is set by default to `TRUE` in `fread` right now and you can also pass `data.table = FALSE` to `fread` to receive a `data.frame` after reading the dataset

Comment: Thanks, the fread function has been upgraded since I first ran into this issue, so this is now the way to go.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `str_trim` from `stringr` package:

```
library(stringr)
testdata[,sapply(.SD,str_trim)]
```

By default it trims whitesapces in both sides, but you can set the side:

```
testdata[,sapply(.SD,str_trim,side="left")]
```

Comment: Thank you, this would have done the trick. However, my colleague has a solution outside of R. He used a PERL command on his local Mac OSX machine to strip padding:
    perl -lape 's/\s+//sg' /path/to/file.csv > /path/to/fileV2.csv
This reduces the file size and strips whitespaces before reading it into R.

Comment: Just a word of caution: using @agstudy's solution will convert numeric columns to chr if these also contain spaces. Otherwise, nice solution.